# ag-grid FullWidthCellRenderer is replacing the complete row

Tags: angular, ag-grid

I am using ag-grid, trying to implement the fullwidth row..to expand the last column "Query". But only query is appearing in the row.

Any help would be appreciated.

```
export class FullWidthCellRenderer {
        public eGui: any;

        // gets called once before the renderer is used
        public init(params) {
            // create the cell
            //this.eGui = document.createElement('div');
            //this.eGui.innerHTML = this.getTemplate(params);

            let eTemp = document.createElement('div');
            eTemp.innerHTML = this.getTemplate(params);
            this.eGui = eTemp.firstElementChild;


            // set value into cell
            //this.eValue.innerHTML = params.value;
        };

        // gets called once when grid ready to insert the element
        public getGui() {
            return this.eGui;
        };

        public getTemplate(params) {
            // the flower row shares the same data as the parent row
            let data = params.node.data;

            let template =
                '<div class="full-width-panel">' +
                '  <div class="full-width-center">' + data.Query +
                '  </div>' +
                '</div>';

            return template;
        };
    }
```

And "gridOptions" as below

```
this.gridOptions = <GridOptions>{
        columnDefs : [
            { headerName: "Name", field: "Name", width: 150},
            { headerName: "abc", field: "abc", width: 150 },
            { headerName: "def", field: "def", width: 150 },
            {
                headerName: "Query", field: "Query", width: 150,
                cellRenderer: "group",

                //cellRendererFramework: {
                //    component: GroupComponent
                //},

                cellRendererParams: { innerRenderer: queryCellRenderer }
            }
        ],
        isFullWidthCell: function (rowNode) {               
            return true;
        },

        fullWidthCellRenderer: FullWidthCellRenderer,

        getRowHeight: function (params) {               
            return 200;
        },
        onGridReady: function (params) {
            // when grid is ready, expand Ireland and UK automatically
            params.api.forEachLeafNode(function (rowNode) {                   
                    rowNode.expanded = true;                  
            });
            params.api.onGroupExpandedOrCollapsed();
        },
        // return true, meaning all data can flower

        doesDataFlower: function (dataItem) {              
            return true;
        }
    };
```

Comment: Did you get this working?

Answer (score 0):

The *isFullWidthCell* shouldn't be always true. try this:

```
isFullWidthCell: (rowNode: RowNode) => { return rowNode.level === 1; }
```

source: https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-grid-master-detail/